# Excel can't show "load my addin" on excel desktop office 365

Tags: excel, excel-addins

When i want to load custom addin (manifest.xml) on one drive. I go to Addin's > Other Addin's > Load my Addin and it's working.
But when i use excel desktop, i can't see "load my addin" and i don't know why

I have try to add my addin domain to the approve domains but nothing change